# Filldown does not populate cells

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**

I'm experiencing a problem in VBA for Excel 365 where the range.filldown function does not fill the specified cells in my worksheet.

**Code Description:**

My code inserts a row above the currently selected cell if the row is greater than 20.  (My workbook has a header section where I don't want new rows added.)

After that, I then use the range.filldown function to fill the cells where I have written formulas.  (When testing, I've been adding the line to the middle of my data set; so, there is data both above and below the line that I am inserting.

**Results/Issue:**

The first two filldown statements that key off of .Cells work as intended and populate with formulas when the code is finished.  However, the filldown that uses .Range does nothing -- the code executes without error and the cells remain empty.

**Other Callouts**

- I've included a comment calling out the line of code that is not working as intended.
- Using a table is not an option for my use case.
- I use three constants which are declared elsewhere in my code.  I've included them for the sake of completeness, but they are currently commented out.

  ```
  Sub insert_sheet_row()
      'Inserts a row into the sheet above the currently selected cell.  Ranges with formulas are specified in
      'this sub and are updated via filldown.

      Dim current_row As Integer
      Dim fcst_total_col_1 As Integer
      Dim fcst_total_col_2 As Integer
      Dim fcst_total_col_3 As Integer

      '''Constants included for upload to Stack Overflow

      'Dim FCST_START_COL As Integer
      'Dim FCST_END_COL As Integer
      'Dim TM_TBL_HEADER_ROW As Integer

      'FCST_START_COL = 14
      'FCST_END_COL = 88
      'TM_TBL_HEADER_ROW = 20

      '''End Constants '''


      'Assign the current row from the active cell.
      current_row = Selection.Row

      'Pattern to select ranges that contain formulas
      fcst_total_col_1 = FCST_START_COL + 4
      fcst_total_col_2 = fcst_total_col_1 + 5
      fcst_total_col_3 = fcst_total_col_2 + 5

      'Only run if current_row is greater than table header -- currently set to integer 20.
      If current_row > TM_TBL_HEADER_ROW Then

          'Insert new row
          Selection.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

          'Fill formulas for appropriate ranges.

          '''These work'''
          ActiveSheet.Cells(current_row, fcst_total_col_1).FillDown
          ActiveSheet.Cells(current_row, fcst_total_col_2).FillDown

          '''This does not work'''
          ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(current_row, fcst_total_col_3), Cells(current_row, FCST_END_COL)).FillDown

          'Printing range for debugging purposes
          Debug.Print (current_row & " " & fcst_total_col_3 & " to " & current_row & " " & FCST_END_COL)
      End If

  End Sub
  ```

Comment: So what does the debug. Print gives you?

Comment: The Debug.Print returns the coordinates for the range that I want to update.  The coordinates for the starting cell are listed first and the coordinates for the end cell last.  So, it would print [start row start col to end row end col].  For instance, if the cell I currently have selected is in row 57, it would return the following: 57 28 to 57 88.

Comment: Well, to my knowledge it is logical is it not doing anything as your start row is row 57 and your end row also so there is nothing to Filldown. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.filldown